# AngularJS - changing input validity from controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a form like so

```
<div ng-controller="controllerPasswordChange">
<form name="form" novalidate>
        <div >
            <label class="control-label screen-reader-text" for="email">Email</label>
            <div>
                <input ng-model="formModel.email" type="email" name="email" class="large-field" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                <div class="input-help">
                    <h4>Invalid Email</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label class="control-label screen-reader-text" for="password">Password</label>
            <div class="controls relative mrl">
                <input name="password" id="password" ng-model="formModel.password" ng-change="checkPasswordCriteria()" required class="immediate-help large-field" type="password" placeholder="Enter new password">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

When the password input changes, the checkPasswordCriteria method is called as follow

```
var checkingPasswordCriteria =  false;
var checkPasswordCriteriaSuccess = function()
{
    console.log("checking password criteria success");
    checkingPasswordCriteria = false;
    // HERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE VALIDITY OF THE PASSWORD FIELD TO TRUE
};

var checkPasswordCriteriaError = function()
{
    console.log("checking password criteria error");
    checkingPasswordCriteria = false;
    // HERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE VALIDITY OF THE PASSWORD FIELD TO FALSE
};

$scope.checkPasswordCriteria = function()
{
    if( !checkingPasswordCriteria )
    {
        checkingPasswordCriteria = true;
        ajaxService.checkPasswordCriteria($scope.formModel.email,$scope.formModel.password,
            checkPasswordCriteriaSuccess, checkPasswordCriteriaError);
    }
};
```

I would like to change the validity of the password input field from my controller, depending on the http result code received.
I have seen ways of changing the validity using directive, but in my case it feels like it is a bit overkill + would be nice to know just for the sake of knowing how to do it...

Cheers,
Xavier

[EDIT]
I have to add I want the validity to be changed as the user type in the input field not when the focus has changed.
[/EDIT]

Answer (score -2):

Passing in the form's password control to checkPasswordCriteria and modifying it inside of that function would do the trick:

```
<div>
    <label class="control-label screen-reader-text" for="password">Password</label>
    <div class="controls relative mrl">
        <input name="password" id="password" ng-model="formModel.password" ng-change="checkPasswordCriteria(form.password)" required class="immediate-help large-field" type="password" placeholder="Enter new password">
    </div>
</div>
```

And inside checkPasswordCriteria, just set the validity on the control based on the response:

```
$scope.checkPasswordCriteria = function (passwordControl) {
    if (!checkingPasswordCriteria) {
        checkingPasswordCriteria = true;

        // Simulating a service call and response
        $timeout(function() {
            passwordControl.$setValidity('valid', Math.random() >= 0.5);
            checkingPasswordCriteria = false;                
        }, 1000);
    }
};
```

Demo Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UHBAu/

Comment: The controller shouldn't know anything about the view to which it is associated.

Comment: controller in sense ngModel in directive.